# hyperlink in powershell script in html table

Tags: html, powershell, hyperlink

i'm new to `powershell` and i don't know lots of things. Script im using atm:

```
$webfile = "\\mywebserver\prn$\index.html"
$mylog = ("\\mywebserver\prn$\log\monitorprinterqueues_" + (Get-Date).month + (Get-Date).day + (Get-Date).year + ".log")

if ((Test-Path $mylog ) -ne $true) {#check for new log
    $myheader = "datetime*owner*jobstatus*queuestatus*totalpages*size*server*queue*document"
    $myheader| out-file -FilePath $mylog -append -noclobber
}#check for new log

function mystatus ($thisstatus) {
    switch ($thisstatus) {
         "0" { $mytext = "Ok" }
         "1" { $mytext = "Other" }
         "2" { $mytext = "Paused" }
         "3" { $mytext = "Low Paper" }
         "4" { $mytext = "No Paper" }
         "5" { $mytext = "Low Toner" }
         "6" { $mytext = "No Toner" }
         "7" { $mytext = "Door Open" }
         "8" { $mytext = "Paper Jam" }
         "9" { $mytext = "Offline" }
         "10" { $mytext = "Output Bin Full" }
         "11" { $mytext = "Paper Problem" }
         "12" { $mytext = "Cannot Print Page" }
         "13" { $mytext = "User Intervention Required" }
         "14" { $mytext = "Out of Memory" }
         "15" { $mytext = "Server Unknown" }
         default {$mytext = "Error (D)" }
    }
return ($mytext)
}

clear
$myservers = @()
$myservers = ("myprintserver1","myprintserver2")

#exporttoweb
Remove-Item ($webfile)
$head = "<style>"
$head = $head + "BODY{background-color:#9FAEB5;}"
$head = $head + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$head = $head + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 4px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:#999999}"
$head = $head + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 4px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:#CCCCCC}"
$head = $head + "</style>"


foreach ($thisserver in $myservers) {
     $prnstats = gwmi win32_printer -ComputerName $thisserver | %{ $prname = $_.Name; $prtname = $_.portname; $srv = $_.systemname; $status = $_.detectederrorstate; $location = $_.location; gwmi win32_tcpipprinterport -computername $thisserver | where { $_.Name -eq $prtname } | select @{name="Name";expression={$prname}}, @{name="Server";expression={$srv}}, @{name="Status";expression={$status}}, @{name="Location";expression={$location}}, hostaddress }
     $printserver = get-wmiobject "Win32_PrintJob" -computername $thisserver | where { ($_.jobstatus -ne $null) -and ($_.jobstatus -ne "") -and ($_.jobstatus -ne "Printing") -and ($_.jobstatus -ne "Spooling") -and ($_.jobstatus -ne "Spooling | Printing")  }
     if ((Test-Path -Path $webfile) -ne $true) {#writehead top
         $prnstats | select Name, Server, @{name="Status";Expression={mystatus $_.Status }}, Location, @{name="Web-Interface";Expression={$_.hostaddress }} | ConvertTo-HTML -head $head -body "<H2>Printer Status Site</H2>" | Out-File $webfile
     } else {
         $prnstats | select Name, Server, @{name="Status";Expression={mystatus $_.Status }}, Location, @{name="Web-Interface";Expression={$_.hostaddress }} | ConvertTo-HTML | Out-File $webfile -Append
     }
     foreach ($printjob in $printserver) {
         if (($printjob.Jobstatus -ne $null) -and ($printjob.Jobstatus -ne "")){
         switch ($printjob.Jobstatus) {

             default { 
                 $prn = $prnstats | where { $_.name -eq ("" + $printjob.Name.split(',')[0]) }
                 $thisstr = "" + $printjob.TimeSubmitted + "*" + $printjob.Owner + "*" + $printjob.JobStatus + "*" + (mystatus $prn.DetectedErrorState) + "*" + $printjob.TotalPages + "*" + $printjob.Size + "*" + $thisserver + "*" + $printjob.Name + "*" + $printjob.Document
                 $thisstr   | out-file -FilePath $mylog -append -noclobber
                 $printjob.Delete()
             }#end default
         }#end switch
         }#end if
     #$printjob = $null
     }#jobs
    $printserver = $null
    #$printjob = $null
} #servers
```

The result is html-table [image: html-table]. Need to do all the hostnames to be hyperlinks. To be able to get the printer's web-interface asap. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Change the `Web-Interface` calculated property expression from

```
@{name="Web-Interface";Expression={$_.hostaddress }}
```

to an actual link (`<a href='url'>link text</a>`)

```
@{name="Web-Interface";Expression={"<a href='http://{0}/'>{0}</a>" -f $_.hostaddress }}
```

Comment: Ty, it worked, but now I have another problem. It seems that powershell converts special symbols. And I see just a html code... In html file symbols "<" and ">" at the beginning and the end of anchors converted to "&lt;" and "&gt;"      &lt;a href='http://ATS-Xerox-5675-1.printers.rosenergo.com/'&gt;    exept of <a href='http://ATS-Xerox-5675-1.printers.rosenergo.com/'>    How can I convert or replace these back to html?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution by adding foreach

```
ConvertTo-HTML -head $head -body "<H2>Printer Status Site</H2>" | foreach {$_.replace("&lt;","<").replace("&gt;",">")} | Out-File $webfile
```

Works fine now.